# jqGrid: Drop downs based on MySQL Query

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jqgrid

I was wondering how to create a basic drop down in the add/edit forms but the values based on the results from a mysql query instead of hard coded values. I read in the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules&s%5B%5D=dataurl) where you can set the editoptions dataurl parameter but it only gives the html which is not helpful. I need to know how the javascript is supposed to be formatted. Am I suppose to create a separate PHP file to house the query statement?

I need to not only display the select id field in the drop down but as well as the id's title description so it makes it easier for the user to associate the id with a title to select the appropriate id for the id input field.

The drop down id field after an id has been selected needs to auto populate several other fields on the add/edit form. The other fields not being drop downs but simple text fields.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**
I've tried your suggestion but I'm unable to get anything to appear in the dropdown on the forms.
Please take a look at my code below...

**jqGrid (Javascript) code in the HTML file:**

```
{name:'div_id',
   index:'div_id', 
   width:30,
   editable:true,
   sortable:false, 
   resizable:false,
   align:"center", 
   edittype:'select',
   editrules:{required:true,number:true},
   formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"},
   editoptions:{
       size:11,
       maxlength:11,
       dataUrl:'dropdown.php',
       type:"GET",
       buildSelect:function(data){
           var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data); //json data
           var s = '<select style="width: 520px">';
           if(response && response.length)     
           { 
               s += '<option value="0">--- Select Value ---</option>';

               for (var i = 0, l=response.length; i<l ; i++) 
               {       
                   var ri = response[i].divid + response[i].longDesc; 
                    s += '<option value="'+ri+'">'+ri+'</option>';                          
               }  // var i = 0, l=response.length; i<l ; i++ 
           } //response && response.length
           return s + "</select>";
       } // function(data) 
},
```

**DataUrl: dropdown.php code**

```
// Connect to the database
$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "root"; 
$dbpass = "**********"; 
$dbname = "codetables"; 

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Error conecting to db.");

$result = mysql_query('SELECT div_id, long_desc FROM divcodes where avail_ind = "Y" and active_ind="Y" order by div_id');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row[id];
    $response->rows[$i]['divid']=array($row[div_id]);
    $response->rows[$i]['longDesc']=array($row[long_desc]);
    $i++;
}        
echo json_encode($response);
```

**JSON Data:**
I only displayed a portion of the JSON data but I do get data from the mysql query and it seems like is get put into the JSON array.

```
{"rows":[{"divid":["01"],"longDesc":["Office of Technology and Information Services"]},{"divid":["04"],"longDesc":["Office of Emergency Response"]},{"divid":["05"]}]}
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**
I was struggling with how to format the data so jqGrid would display the data in the dropdown. I was able to figure it out but the format will change again when I switch to PDO statments. But for the time being here is what I found out...

**Data URL: dropdown.php code**

```
$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "root"; 
$dbpass = "*********"; 
$dbname = "maint"; 

// connect to the database
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Error conecting to db.");

$result = mysql_query('SELECT div_id FROM depdivs where div_id <> "" and avail_ind = "Y" and active_ind="Y"');

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[$i]=array($row[div_id]);
    $i++;
}        
echo json_encode($rows);
```

**JSON Data Output:**

```
[["01"],["02"],["03"],["04"],["52"],["53"],["55"],["57"],["58"],["60"],["75"]]
```

**jqGrid (Javascript) code in the HTML file:**

```
{name:'div_id',
    index:'div_id', 
    width:30,
    editable:true,
    sortable:false, 
    resizable:false,
    align:"center",
    edittype:'select',
    editrules:{required:true,number:true},
    formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"},
    editoptions:{
           dataUrl:'dropdown.php',
           buildSelect: function(response){
                 var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                 var s = '<select>';
                 jQuery.each(response,function(i,item){
                       s +='<option value="+response[i]+'">'+response[i]+'</option>';
                 });
                 return s + "</select>";
           }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps,

In your colmodel

```
editoptions: { 
 dataUrl:'your url',
 type:"GET",
 buildSelect: function(data) {
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data); //json data
        var s = '<select style="width: 520px">';
        if (response && response.length) { //
            s += '<option value="0">--- Select Value ---</option>';
            for (var i = 0, l=response.length; i<l ; i++) {
            var ri = response[i].value; // u can concatenate id here
                s += '<option value="'+ri+'">'+ri+'</option>';
            }
        }
        return s + "</select>";
        },
  } ,
```

Here i am returning json data as
 `[{"id":"1","value":"Alpha"},{"id":"2","value":"Beta"}]`

If u want to display my id , just concat with response value

```
var ri = response[i].value + response[i].id;
```

## UPDATE

```
List<ArticleDetails> articlelist =  prfbo.getPrfArticleType(); // get value from DB
JSONArray jsonOrdertanArray = JSONArray.fromObject(articlelist);

System.out.println(jsonOrdertanArray);
out.println(jsonOrdertanArray);
```

Comment: @klm guess the issue is with the format. So try to change {"rows":
  {"divid":"01","longDesc":"Office of Technology and Information Services"},
  {"divid":"04","longDesc":"Office of Emergency Response"},
  and so on....
}

Comment: How did you write/format your code to connect to the data? How can I get my JSON code to be similar to your output because everytime I take out something out of these lines of code it says there's a syntax error. `$response->rows[$i]['divid']=array($row[div_id]);
    $response->rows[$i]['longDesc']=array($row[long_desc]);`

Comment: sorry i don't know php. i use java servlets. but the concept remains same,